# Разбираемся с STL в контексте таблиц по типу БД

Tags: stl, c++

Стоит задача, реализовать эффективный способ обработки данных, которые пердставляют собой таблицу (по типу таблиц БД), в которых есть поля (столбцы одного типа), и записи (строки). Поля будут только двух типов - string, double. Возможное колличество записей (строк) до 3 000 000! Полей (столбцов) до 20. Пологаю, что для реализации лучше использовать STL, контейнер vector. Вопрос по прежнему об эффективной реализации структуры хранения и обработки данных! Какие будут мнения!?

Comment: Просьба помочь решить задачу с неполными исходными данными?

Comment: Полные исходные данные не нужны, задача решается в общем виде (универсальна), я думаю разбить данную таблицу на две, одна будет содержать double, другая string данные...

Comment: Почему бы Вам СУБД какую-нибудь не использовать?

Comment: В моей задаче само приложение должно работать по типу СУБД, только не через SQL, а через DDE обмен!

Comment: вот и прикрутите к нему скажем SQLite

Comment: Эх... тогда сам буду делать! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак есть класс Table и класс Record

```
  class Record{
  public:
      Record(unsigned long dwDblNum, unsigned long dwStrNum){
          if (dwDblNum) pDblTab=new double[dwDblNum];
          if (dwStrNum) pStrTab=new string[dwStrNum];
      }
      ~Record(){
          if(pStrTab) delete[] pStrTab;
          if(pDblTab) delete[] pDblTab;
      }
      string *pStrTab;
      double *pDblTab;
  };
```

Класс Table:

```
class Table{
public:
    Table():dwRowsNum(0), dwColumnsNum(0){};
    ~Table(){};
    void InitTable(unsigned long dwRowsNumber, unsigned long dwColumnsNumber, unsigned short *pTypeFields);
    unsigned long dwRowsNum;
    unsigned long dwColumnsNum; 
    vector <Record> vecRecord;

};
```

Метод InitTable служит для инициализации таблицы, параметры:

```
dwRowsNumber - Количество строк   
dwColumnsNumber - Количество столбцов   
pTypeFields - Массив соответсвия столбца конкретному типу (double-1, string-2)
```